# Programmatically add button to block

Tags: 7, blocks

7 - How do I programmatically create a button, place it in a block, 'weight it' and then make it visible to certain pages?

Code I've tried:

```
function openid_connect_block_info() {
  $blocks['openid_connect_login'] = array(
      'info' => t('Login Using PixelPin'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE | DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
      'region' => 'content',
      'pages' => 'user/',
  );

  $blocks['openid_connect_register'] = array(
      'info' => t('Register Using PixelPin'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE | DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
      'region' => 'content',
      'pages' => '/user/register',
  );
  return $blocks;
}
```

This code creates the button but doesn't put it under the content block and doesn't make it only visible on the specified pages.

Answer (score 1):

Why not render in a tpl so you can control the look of it?

I see you already used `hook_block_info()` so you can complete this using `hook_block_view()` with a custom callback function to use `hook_theme()`

Here is a complete example of it:

```
function openid_connect_block_info() {
  $blocks['openid_connect_login'] = array(
      'info' => t('Login Using PixelPin'),
      'cache' => DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_ROLE | DRUPAL_CACHE_PER_PAGE,
      'region' => 'content',
      'pages' => 'user/',
  );

  return $blocks;
}
```

then:

```
function openid_connect_block_view($delta = '') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'openid_connect_login':
      $block['content'] = openid_connect_login();
      break;
  return $block;
}
```

then:

```
function openid_connect_login() {
  return theme('openid_connect_login_tpl', array('data' => NULL));
}
```

last thing here:

```
    function openid_connect_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
      return array(
        'openid_connect_login_tpl' => array(
          'variables' => array('data' => NULL),
          'template' => 'openid-connect-login',
          'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'openid_connect') . '/theme',
        ),  
);
}
```

create your file inside you module under the name we gave openid-connect-login.tpl.php and put it in a folder I named theme ..

I hope I understood it right and was helpful for you issue ..

Comment: So do i put openid_connect_theme in it's own file under the theme folder?

Comment: the openid_connect_theme() function should still be in the module file ,, but tpl file (openid-connect-login.tpl.php) should be in the theme folder yes